# Galois group is $S_n$ then $L$ is the splitting field of a degree $n$ polynomial

Tags: galois-theory, galois-extensions

I am revisiting Galois Theory and am faced with the following problem.

Let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension whose Galois group is isomorphic to $S_n$. Show that L is the splitting field of a separable polynomial of degree $n$.

My idea, is that since the extension is normal, we know $L = $ Split$_K(f)$ for some $f\in K[X]$, so we want to use Orbit-Stabilizer or something to show $deg(f) = n$.

Comment: "Revising" or "Revisiting"? ;-)

Comment: Sorry? I Haven't seen this problem before.

Comment: If you are "revising" Galois Theory, you are changing the theory, which, considering how well-established it is, I wouldn't advise you do. If you are "revisiting" Galois Theory, then you are re-learning it, which is a great thing to do.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2292604/counting-the-number-of-galois-conjugates